# Is C++ 0x/TR1 safe to use when portability matters?

Tags: c++, c++11, portability

C++03 is lacking some things I'd *love* to use: `std::shared_ptr`, `std::function` and `std::bind`.

We can't fully switch to C++11, because the project needs to work with older libstdc++ versions. I know that this stuff is in Boost as well, but we cannot use that for other reasons.

Hence we started to use C++ 0x/TR1, which is supported by all the compiler versions we currently use. But we're having some trouble with it:

- There's very little information about what of TR1 is implemented in which version of Clang/MSVC/GCC
- I cannot figure out what the `-std=c++0x` switch does in Clang, compiles fine without it
- I'm not sure what namespaces to use, e.g. `std::tr1::shared_ptr` vs `std::shared_ptr`

So, the question: Is C++ 0x/TR1 safe to use when portability matters? Is it implemented in all major compilers? Should I worry about proprietary toolchains etc.? Are we better off sticking to C++03?

Comment: "safe" in what respect? In "production" code, you should be testing and validating your product-code with unit and full system testing. This is what ensures that you have something that actually does what you expect it to do. Just because some document states that `std::xxx` does whatever it says it should do in the standard document, doesn't mean that compiler X and library Y will actually perform the correct operations. And of course, you can't really deliver source-code that is supposed to work with compiler X and library Y without testing it in that combination.

Comment: You are asking us to cross reference all the docs for you. Each compiler vendor should be providing the list of the features they support at a given version. MSVC, GCC, Clang do. I bet that Intel and IBM do too.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You're right, it was ambigious. Rephrased this, since I pretty much only mean safe in the sense of portability.

Comment: TR1 is a pure C++98 library. It should be well supported by most modern C++98 compilers.

Comment: @J.N. When it comes to compiler support, the features we're using seem to be fine. There's little information from the vendors on this, but I don't mind testing. What I'm wondering about is: Is TR1 intended to be used when portability matters? Or is it more like some bleeding edge stuff for bleeding edge folks?

Comment: I still don't really see what the issue is, unless you are producing some sort of source code library that is supposed to compile on anything from 10+ year old compilers to modern ones, and with almost any OS/compiler combination available.

Comment: Well TR1 is like the version before C++11. That last is already two years old. Most of TR1 was in boost before. Hardly cutting edge.

Comment: @MatsPetersson It's a game. Right now, it needs to compile with Clang 3.2, GCC 4.0 and MSVC 2010 to support all the systems we want to support.

Comment: @J.N. But is it really used in practice? I mean, Clang 3.2 doesn't seem to use the std::tr1 namespace and puts stuff in std:: instead. Clang 4.2 does have std::tr1. With GCC, we need to include from the tr1 directory... it's all a bit messy.

Comment: So, Clang 3.2 supports C++0x, which is "the bits of C++11 that we think are safe to implement so far". gcc 4.0 is really quite old by now, that's probably the hardest one - any chance you can get to a more modern gcc version - 4.6 to 4.8 has good support for C++0x/11 versions. But the key is "if it compiles and your testing finds that it works, then it's OK to use" (unless you write code for nuclear power stations or medical equipment etc, where there is a list of "These functions are OK, anything else is strictly forbidden"). For a game, that's not a problem.

Comment: Is your use of clang on an Apple platform (OS X or iOS)?

Comment: @HowardHinnant No, it's in fact for Emscripten. It only supports Clang 3.2 right now :( But I'm working on OSX and use Clang 4.2 to compile the desktop version.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Checked just for fun, and it turns out libcxx used in Emscripten is the issue, not Clang 3.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TR1 is an experiment made by the C++ standards committee.  The purpose of the experiment is to get field experience for libraries, with the hope of standardizing them in a future standard.

TR1 is not a normative standard.

The spec of TR1 specifies the use of namespace `std::tr1`.  The reason things were not put into namespace `std` is to allow the committee more freedom in modifying the TR1 specification on the way to standardization.  And yes, modifications were made in places when most of TR1 was standardized in C++11.

The TR1 document begins with these words:

> This technical report is non-normative. Some of the library components
>   in this technical report may be considered for standardization in a
>   future version of C++, but they are not currently part of any C++
>   standard. Some of the components in this technical report may never be
>   standardized, and others may be standardized in a substantially
>   changed form.
>
> The goal of this technical report it to build more widespread existing
>   practice for an expanded C++ standard library. It gives advice on
>   extensions to those vendors who wish to provide them.

Most, but not all of TR1, was widely implemented in in the 2005 time frame across gcc and MSVC.  The [llvm libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) was developed after the TR1 time frame and was targeted straight at the new C++11 standard, which moves many TR1 components into namespace `std`, and makes them *normative* (required by a standard).

Clang is known to be used with both [llvm libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) and gcc's libstdc++.

I do not know which implementations of the std::lib you need to be portable among.  If all of the places you need to port to implement TR1, it is safe, otherwise it is not.  But TR1 is not a normative standard.  C++98, C++03 and C++11 are normative standards.

> Checked just for fun, and it turns out libcxx used in Emscripten is
>   the issue, not Clang 3.2.

I have coached many, many project owners on how to make their code which uses TR1 portable across libstdc++ (has TR1) and libc++ (has C++11).  libc++ places those TR1 components that were standardized into C++11 in namespace `std` as specified in C++11.  It does this even when -std=c++03.  This was done as a transition aid.  libc++ does not try to be a C++03 conforming library.  It's life starts with C++11.

libc++ has a version number macro called `_LIBCPP_VERSION`.  If this macro is defined after include'ing a std-header, you are using libc++, else you are not.  So you can write code like this:

```
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
// using libc++

#include <memory>
typedef std::shared_ptr<MyType> MyTypePtr;

#else  // !_LIBCPP_VERSION
// not using libc++

#include <tr1/memory>
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<MyType> MyTypePtr;

#endif  // _LIBCPP_VERSION
```

Note that you must have first included some std-header for `_LIBCPP_VERSION` to get defined or not.  If you need to gratuitously include a std-header to see if `_LIBCPP_VERSION` gets defined, use:

```
#include <ciso646>  // detect std-lib
```

C++98/03/11 specify `<ciso646>` to do absolutely nothing.  So it is very cheap to include.  The libc++ implementation of this header does nothing but define `_LIBCPP_VERSION`.

Once done, your code can now easily switch among libc++ and other libraries which implement TR1.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for :) One question: While you do provide a workaround for using TR1 in libc++, I don't get the impression that you consider using TR1 a good idea. Is it a real alternative to Boost (if I only want the stuff in TR1), or a last resort?

Comment: TR1 is an experimental specification, and a transition stepping stone between two standards C++03 and C++11.  Use it knowing that fact.  I would think that eventually and gradually most C++ code will migrate to the current C++ standard, or a more recent C++ standard.  The current C++ standard is C++11.  I'm guessing that in a year, C++11 will be version-1, and the current will be C++14.  There is also a C++17 on the horizon.  By then TR1 will be a fading memory.  By setting up a port to libc++ in your code today, you are actually preparing your code for the future.

Comment: Sounds like a good route then. My intention is pretty much to migrate to C++11 as soon as I reasonably can. The parts of it supported in the compilers I need to support, that is...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make TR1 work on all your different compilers, I would just take the boost code (header-only) and copy-paste it into your own project (since you can't use boost directly for whatever reason). The boost versions are well supported and debugged, and will work consistently across any C++98 compiler that is supported by boost.

Comment: The problem is that boost is (in general) inter-connected that you could end up copy-pasting half of it.

Comment: What @Angew said... I need 20 MB of headers just for shared_ptr. Actually, Boost TR1 looks like it's _just_ what I want, but a decision was made not to use Boost, I can't overrule that without reasons beyond "there are a few handy classes in there". Hence my desire to use TR1.